Connecting Harbor with Docker repository in Nexus
We have the following use case:

Nexus Repository server storing all Docker images.
K8s cluster in VMWare Tanzu environment
Harbor Docker registry server in VMWare Tanzu environment

Goal: Deployments in K8s should pull Docker images from the Harbor server.
As the Harbor server is 'near' the cluster, the downloads from there onto the pods should be fast.
Current challenge: How to connect Harbor with Nexus Repository?
In Harbor, we created a proxy cache project with a corresponding replication endpoint pointing at a Docker repo in Nexus. Nevertheless, Harbor CANNOT establish the connection!

Harbor CANNOT establish the connection - then debug that part. Read log files, confirm network connectivity, routing, firewalls etc.
